# JSF : How create custom validator to birthdate?

Tags: jsf, date, jsf-2, validation

I would like to create the selected birthdate with a custom validator.
This is my view:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="birthdate_day" value="#{userc.userb.b_day}">
            <f:validator validatorId="dateExistValidator" />
            <f:attribute name="day" value="#{dateExist.submittedValue}" />
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_birthdate_day" />

            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dia" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{userc.birthDateDays}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="birthdate_month" value="#{userc.userb.b_month}" binding="#{dateExist}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Mês" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{userc.birthDateMonths}" var="month" itemValue="#{month.key}" itemLabel="#{month.value}" />
            <f:ajax event="blur" execute="birthdate_day birthdate_month" render="m_birthdate_month" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="birthdate_year" value="#{userc.userb.b_year}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ano" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{userc.birthDateYears}" />
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_birthdate_year" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is my validator:

```
@FacesValidator("dateExistValidator")
public class DateValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        Integer day =   (Integer) value;
        Integer month = (Integer) component.getAttributes().get("month");
        Integer year =  (Integer) component.getAttributes().get("year");

        if (day == null || month == null || year == null) {
            return; // Just ignore and let required="true" do its job.
        }

        // do the verifications if the selected date exist
    }
}
```

But for some reason, my `month` and `year` object in my validator is always null.
To be honest I don't know how to link the selected value in the `selectItems` to my `validator.`

How can I do that ? Or should I do this validation only when the user submit the form ?

Comment: Related: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you posted code incomplete?

Any way this should work

```
    <h:selectOneMenu id="birthdate_day" value="#{userc.userb.b_day}">
        <f:validator validatorId="dateExistValidator" />

        <f:attribute name="month" value="#{myMonth}" />
        <f:attribute name="year" value="#{myYear}" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_birthdate_day" />

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dia" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{userc.birthDateDays}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="birthdate_month" value="#{userc.userb.b_month}" binding="#{myMonth}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="M?s" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{userc.birthDateMonths}" var="month" itemValue="#{month.key}" itemLabel="#{month.value}" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" execute="birthdate_day birthdate_month" render="m_birthdate_month" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="birthdate_year" value="#{userc.userb.b_year}" binding="#{myYear}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ano" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{userc.birthDateYears}" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_birthdate_year" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Also , to get the value from the attributes you should convert them to their *UIElement* first and than extract their value  , for example

```
UISelectOne month = (UISelectOne) component.getAttributes().get("myMonth");
month.getSubmittedValue()
```

Comment: Sorry posting the code incomplete for the case of `year`, I didn't notice that. Thank you for your solution, it solve my problem. Thanks!